# Moodle password check on external script

Tags: php, hash, moodle, password-encryption, moodle-api

I have Moodle 2.7. Users logins and passwords hashes is stored in mdl_user table. I want to create external script that can check - if login and password are correct.

As i see - this moodle version use some function php like **password_hash()** to generate password hash.

My php version is 5.4 so i can't use this function. So i use this library https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat with this code

```
$password_hash = password_hash( $password , PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array());
```

The problem is that hash is different each time i calculate it. So i cant compare this hash to string that is placed in mdl_user table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this function is similar to that of the `password_hash()` native to PHP, the salt is generated **along** with the hash, and the salt is randomized. Because of this, comparing the results of 2 separate calls of `password_hash()` are not going to match.

The function you're looking for `password_verify()`, which takes the inputted password and the hash on the database. If this returns true, then the passwords match.